# Issues with Select user in GrdiView

Tags: powershell

I am working on adding a function to a tool i have built where a name is input or part of GridView pulls all the results you select the one then it outputs the result. I have managed to get the first part but cannot seem to get it to output the selection.

I seem to get the below error. I am not sure why exactly. I presume that somewhere i have not told the code what info to pull.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:38 char:9
+         [void]$Users.Add($SelectedUser)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The code of a test gui i am using to test it is below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$CheckUsers                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$CheckUsers.ClientSize           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(507,173)
$CheckUsers.text                 = "CheckUsers"
$CheckUsers.TopMost              = $false

$CheckLocked                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckLocked.text                = "Check Locked Users"
$CheckLocked.width               = 138
$CheckLocked.height              = 30
$CheckLocked.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(309,65)
$CheckLocked.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "User"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(93,38)
$Label1.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$User                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User.multiline                  = $false
$User.width                      = 179
$User.height                     = 20
$User.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(29,70)
$User.Font                       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$CheckUsers.controls.AddRange(@($CheckLocked,$Label1,$User))

$CheckLocked.Add_Click($checkLocked_Click)

#Function checks whether a user is locked in Active Directory
$checkLocked_Click = {
    $ReturnedUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$($User.text)*'" -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordLastSet | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordLastSet
    if ($ReturnedUser.count -gt 1) {
        $SelectedUser = $ReturnedUser | 
            Out-GridView -Title "Multiple Users have matched, select User to process" -OutputMode Single
        [void]$Users.Add($SelectedUser)
    }elseif ($ReturnedUser.count -eq 1) {
        [void]$Users.Add($ReturnedUser)
    }else{
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('No usaers found')
    }
}


[void]$CheckUsers.ShowDialog()
```

In fact the above is one of about three or four different writings of it i have tried. Any help would be appreciated. I get the list of Ben's for example then i select the Ben i want click ok and i get the error.

Thanks in advance All.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized $Users therefore it's $null and can't have methods.

Add:

```bsh
$Users = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. It now doesn't error or display selection. Added under [void]$Users.Add($SelectedUser)